# Return data specific to user logged in MVC5 Identity 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm writing an app with tasks allocated to 10 or so people, however neither of them are able to see other peoples tasks.

I'm using Identity to do this but my where condition isn't returning the correct data. 
This is my controller;

```
        this.ApplicationDbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
        this.UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(this.ApplicationDbContext));

        ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());

        var pipeline = db.STasks
            .Where(s => s.UserID == user.Id)
            .Include(s => s.Type)
            .Include(s => s.Location)
            .Include(s => s.Customer)
            .Include(s => s.Category)
            .Include(s => s.User);

        return View(pipeline.ToList());
```

All tasks are returned if I remove the `.Where()` condition, however none of them are returned if if I keep it.

How can I diagnose this?

Comment: What is the value of `user.Id` ? Do you have records in the STasks table with UserID value equal the previously mentioned value (user.Id) ?

Comment: Yeah, I've manually copied the record from aspnetusers to the UserID column. When I execute the query inside SQL Server management studio and replace the parameter with the user.ID value I get the correct data returned.

Comment: **neither of them are able to see other peoples tasks.** Where is your code to do that ? Looks like you are filtering based on the UserID property value. I am not sure that will address your requirement.